# Initialize a GameScene in Swift - Xcode 6.3

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skscene

I am trying to initialize a scene in swift like so: `let scene = GameScene(size: skView.bounds.size)`

However the following error pops up in xcode:

> Cannot invoke initializer for type 'GameScene' with an argument list of type '(size: CGSize)

Here is the related piece of code:

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {

    var skView: SKView = self.view as! SKView
    skView.showsFPS = true
    skView.showsNodeCount = true

    let scene = GameScene(size: skView.bounds.size)
    scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
    skView.presentScene(scene)

}
```

Comment: maybey this helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27792514/cannot-invoke-init-with-argument-list-of-type-stringliteralconvertible

Answer (score -1):

You probably might want to include the following initializer within your `GameScene`

```
override init(size: CGSize) {

    super.init(size: size)

}
```